Relationship between Pythagorean Triples and double/half angles
I just happened upon something that I had never noticed before. I was doing a problem given $\tan u = \frac34$ where $0<u<\frac\pi 2$, find the exact values of $\sin 2u$, $\cos 2u$, and $\tan 2u$ using the double angle formulas. Now, of course, $u$ corresponds to the Pythagorean Triple 3-4-5. When I calculated the results $\sin 2u=\frac{24}{25}$, $\cos 2u=\frac{7}{25}$, and $\tan 2u=\frac{24}{7}$, I realized these correspond to the Pythagorean Triple 7-24-25. I am curious to know if there is a good reason for this relationship and if it is just a one off? Or are there other Pythagoreon Triples that are related in this same way? (Obviously, just looking at primitive Pythgaorean Triples, not multiples of these same triples).

I think you might really enjoy this video by 3Blue1Brown about the connection between generating Pythagorean triples and multiplying Gaussian integers (complex numbers with integer components).

Think about the coordinates of a point in the complex plane. Any two integers.  Now square that complex number, and you got two elements of a Pyth triple. (The third element would be the absolute value of the square.)  Remember that when you square a complex number, you double its angle and square its magnitude.

If $\tan x =\frac{a}{b}$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then,
$$\sin 2x =\frac{2ab}{c^2}, \quad \cos 2x=\frac{b^2-a^2}{c^2}, \quad \tan2x=\frac{2ab}{b^2-a^2}.$$
Now,
\begin{align*}
(2ab)^2+(b^2-a^2)^2 & = (a^2+b^2)^2\\
&= (c^2)^2
\end{align*}
Thus $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triplet, then $(b^2-a^2,\, 2ab, \, \underbrace{a^2+b^2}_{\color{\red}{c^2}})$ also forms a Pythagorean triplet.
For example, $(5,12,13)$ is a PPT and so is $(119,120,169)$.

That's neat! Thanks for the answer. I love finding out a new nugget about relatively simple math.

This is closely related to complex numbers. If $z=a+bi$ is located on a Pythagorean triple, then $z^2=a^2-b^2+2abi$ is also located on a Pythagorean triple.

It's just by the bisector.
We have two right triangles of triples $(3,4,5)$ and $(24,7,25)$ but defined by a bisector wich divided the side of lenght $24$ into two segments $x,y$ so $x +y=24$. Besides one has the equations $x^2+7^2=z^2$ and
$y^2=25^2+z^2-2\times25\left(\dfrac45\right)$. These three equations have the solution $(x,y,z)=\left(\dfrac{21}{4},\dfrac{75}{4},\dfrac{35}{4}\right)$ and we can verify the theorem of the bisector
$$\frac{25}{\dfrac{75}{4}}=\frac{7}{\dfrac{21}{4}}\iff525=525$$ It's all due to the bisector.

HINT:
Draw a right angled triangle in a semicircle radius R=1. A bisector is the radius, please note.
Identify and solve for $(u,v)$ segments;
$$ u+v=2R;~ uv= ( 2mn)^2~;$$
Plug them into:
$$ \sin 2 \theta=\frac{2mn}{R},$$
$$ \cos 2 \theta=\frac{R-v}{R},$$
$$ \tan 2 \theta=\frac{2mn}{u}.$$

Generally, if $(a,b,c)$ and $(A,B,C)$ are Pythagorean triples, then so is $(aA-bB,aB+bA,cC).$
This follows from the addition laws of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Letting $\cos\alpha=a/c,$ $\sin\alpha=b/c,$ $\cos\beta=A/C,$ $\sin\beta=B/C$ we get
$$
\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha \sin\beta
= \frac a c \frac A C - \frac b c \frac B C = \frac{aA-bB}{cC} \\
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha \cos\beta + \cos\alpha \sin\beta
= \frac b c \frac A C + \frac a c \frac B C = \frac{aB+bA}{cC}
$$
With $(a,b,c)=(A,B,C)$ we get the Pythagorean triple $(a^2-b^2,2ab,c^2),$ i.e. $(a^2-b^2)^2 + (2ab)^2 = (c^2)^2.$ In the case $(a,b,c)=(4,3,5)$ we get $(7,24,25).$
Also interesting is that the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ has an infinite number of points where both $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers. The points $(\pm1, 0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$ are trivial, but we also have for example $(3/5,4/5)$ and $(5/13,12/13).$

Quite a few ago I had similar discoveries and wrote a nice paper on this:
Dr. Michael W. Ecker, Linking All Pythagorean Triples, Mathematics and Computer Education, October 2008, Vol. 42, No. 3; p. 238–248.
Here is the opening paragraph (minus proper formatting):
"Perhaps I first saw it 20 years ago while teaching complex numbers in precalculus.
If  z = 3 + 4i, then z^2 = -7 + 24i . Curious, I thought: One starts with a complex number representing two legs of the 3-4-5 right triangle, and squaring yields a complex number that represents two legs of another right triangle, the 7-24-25.
What's going on here?"
At 10+ pages, I won't try to print or even summarize it here, but since the journal went under around 2015, it's not generally available. However, if you email me at DrMWEcker @ aol.com I will mail a copy to anybody who requests same. (I am not selling anything and just want to share. I hope I am not breaking any site rules making this offer, and apologize if I am.)

Let $\quad \sin 2A = 2 \sin A \cos A
 \qquad \cos 2A = \cos^2 A − \sin^2 A\quad$
where $\quad \sin A =  \dfrac{b}{c} \qquad \cos A = \dfrac{a}{c}$
Then $\quad \sin2A = 2\cdot\dfrac{b}
{c}\cdot\dfrac{a}{c} = \dfrac{2ab}{c^2}
\qquad \cos2A=\dfrac{b^2}{c^2}
-\dfrac{a^a}{c^2}= \dfrac{b^2-a^2}{c^2}$
Then
\begin{align*}
(3,4,5)\longrightarrow\sin(2A)=
 \dfrac{2\cdot3\cdot4}{5^2}=\dfrac{24}{25}
\newline\newline
\cos(2A)= \dfrac{4^2-3^2}{5^2}
=\dfrac{7}{25}
\end{align*}
$\textbf{Note: }$ Technically, $\theta=A\,$ should be the angle adjacent to the longer leg for $\,\theta\,$ to be less than $45˚\,$ but the calculations work either way. The absolute value(s) of $\,\sin(2A)\,$ and $\,\cos(2A)\,$ may be used to avoid negative terms in the generated triples such as $\,(15,8,17)\longrightarrow (-161,240,289).$
For brevity, the tangent has been omitted but any Pythagorean triple components can be used to generate another Pythagorean triple.
